# python - .txt file write everything on the same line

Tags: python, file

I am new to python and I have a problem, I am writing a program that searches for keywords in a .log file and stores them in a .txt file. My problem is when I store the word they all are written on the same line after each other... I want one word per line, ist it possible to do that?

For example, now it is a single, long line of "Complete Response:"

```
Complete Response:, Complete Response:, Complete Response:, Complete Response:, Complete Response:, Complete Response:, Complete Response:.....
```

I need the following response.

```
Complete Response:,

Complete Response:,

Complete Response:,

Complete Response:,

Complete Response:,

.......
```

my code

```
def read_log_file(filename, text): # file

    important = []

    with open(filename) as f:   #open search file
        f = f.readlines()   #read searrch file
    for lines in f:
        for line in lines:
            f.write(line + '\n')
            if text in lines:   #if keyword is found take all lines
                important.append(lines.split(','))     #store all found keywords
    print('done')
        # file or 'sorted.txt'
    with open('sorted.txt', 'w') as file_handler:
        file_handler.write(f"\n{filename}\n")
        file_handler.write(f" Status: {important} \n")
        print(len(important))
```

Comment: An explicit code example?

Comment: if you are printing \n but cant seem them, then you are probably print LF and viewing the file in windows, which expect CRLF. just open the file in a smarter text viewer, such as notepad++

Comment: What are you using to open the txt file after?